# codeigniter 3 CSRF token in controller without sending request from FORM or AJAX

Tags: codeigniter, csrf, csrf-token

I have an application in codeigniter 3 in which CSRF token was false, but now I want to update CSRF tokent to TRUE. If CSRF token is true in config then I have to pass this using either form_open or in ajax like

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_test_name" value="80bfb80b356d6d31f4ce4dad0c6cf69e">
```

. But there are lots of forms to update this. Is there any way I can manage CSRF token without sending from form or ajax request.

I enabled CSRF to true

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
```

and tried to get it in constructor of controller

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();
        $this->security->get_csrf_hash();
    }
```

But getting error as

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> The action you have requested is not allowed.

If I add

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_test_name" value="80bfb80b356d6d31f4ce4dad0c6cf69e">
```

its working fine, but I don't want to do this as there are lots of form.

Any help would be appreciable.